# Does rsync make a backup copy or a history of backup copies?

Tags: backup, rsync, rollback

Many tutorial sites mention making hourly/daily/weekly backups with rsync [[1]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=240326), [[2]](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/), and even more claim to set up rsync like Mac's Time Machine [[3]](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html), [[4]](http://www.jan-muennich.de/linux-backups-time-machine-rsyn), [[5]](http://developercoach.com/2010/using-rsync-and-time-machine-for-web-site-backups/). But when I look at the code, it seems like they make `currentBackup/` folder, next time around they `rsync` against this `currentBackup` to only copy over the changes necessary, then delete the `currentBackup` and set the new folder to be `currentBackup`. But what if I want daily backups likes so

```
March-10-44-BC/
March-11-44-BC/
March-12-44-BC/
March-13-44-BC/
March-14-44-BC/
March-15-44-BC/
```

So on March 16 I can 'roll back' to the March 15 version or the March 14 version. I have noticed each site mentions something called `hard links`. Since I can't understand what this is, perhaps this retains information capable of performing 'roll backs'. If not, what am I supposed to do? Keep all previous backups and `tar.gz` them?

Comment: You can combine `git` with `rsync` to keep an archive of changes: first `rsync`, then `git add -A` then `git commit -m "\`date +%B-%d-%y-BC\`"`.  Then create a script to automatically squash commits, keeping only the desired intervals.  To rollback, simply checkout the day you want (`git checkout My_DATE`) and rsync back to the source folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these purposes hard links serve as "copy on write" copies of the files.  If a file is unchanged, hard linked "copies" of it don't take up any extra space.  When the file is changed, because of the hard links, a new copy with the changes is created instead.  [See Wikipedia for more information.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)

So rsync does mainly backup, but can provide some archiving functionality as well.  This is in contrast to other backup software like Time Machine that always and automatically provide archiving as well as backup.

Comment: thherefore, rsync doesn't inherently provide a history of backups, like Time machine, correct?

Comment: Correct.  Rsync is designed mostly for backup, whereas Time Machine does of what's often termed archiving.

Comment: Can you move the previous comment into the answer as it is the answer I was actually looking for.